# Referring to an Area of a Named Range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

Named ranges can contain multiple areas, which are just references separated by a comma. What notation is used to refer to an area of a named range?

For example, I have put the alphabet in columns A-D. Column A has A-G, column B has  H-O, column C has P-U, and column D has V-Z. My named range is called Alphabet and the reference looks like this:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$8,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$6,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$5
```

Is there a built-in notation for referring to an area of a named range? I have found that I can get the entirety of column B alone by using `INDEX` as such:

```
{=INDEX(Alphabet,,,2)}
```

Which handily returns the array `{"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"O"}`.

This does not solve my problem, though. I want to be able to count the number of rows in each area of each range. I have tried dereferencing the number of areas in the range and passing that to `INDEX` and then running `ROWS` on it as an array function, but that fails, because as soon as you pass an array to the area_num  parameter of `INDEX` it only returns the first row of each area. The failing example:

```
{=INDEX(Alphabet,,,N(IF({1},ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,AREAS(Alphabet))))))}
```

This returns the array `{"A";"H";"P";"V"}` which is not what I am looking for since I would like to count the rows in each area.

Looking strictly for a formula only (i.e. no VBA) solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm really close, but can't seem to get it right. Created a second named range called `Alphabet_Areas` - 

`=ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,AREAS(Alphabet)))`

Then I can do an array formula in cells and get the right answer, but not as an F9 evaluation. Semi-working formula is - 

`{=IF(Alphabet_Areas,ROWS(INDEX(Alphabet,,,Alphabet_Areas)))}`

Comment: Jenn - Your solution would be correct if my named range did not have multiple areas. All but the last formula fail with `#REF` because it does not know what area to apply the formulas to. The last formula somehow comes up with 1 which is an incorrect answer.

Comment: Just two offtopic hints: You should post your comment directly below the answer of @Jenn, to ensure author gets a message. If you explicitly add a user's name, add the @ before the name :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the address of a named range:

```
ADDRESS(ROW(Alphabet),COLUMN(Alphabet))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(Alphabet)+ROWS(Alphabet)-1,COLUMN(Alphabet)+COLUMNS(Alphabet)-1)
```

Get the first row / last row of a named range:

```
=ROW(Alphabet) / =ROWS(Alphabet)
```

Get the first column / last column of a named range:

```
=COLUMN(Alphabet) / =COLUMNS(Alphabet)
```

Get the range of the 3rd column of a named range:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(Alphabet),COLUMN(Alphabet)+3-1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(Alphabet)+ROWS(Alphabet)-1,COLUMN(Alphabet)+3-1)
```

Count the non-blank cells in the 3rd column of a named range:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Alphabet),COLUMN(Alphabet)+3-1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(Alphabet)+ROWS(Alphabet)-1,COLUMN(Alphabet)+3-1)))
```